# Active storage not working on localhost after start use variants

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

Using `:local` as storage in localhost isn't working.
I'm getting the following error

```
Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true
```

My code to call a profile picture

```
def profile_picture
  picture = if self.image.attached? then self.image else Config.first.default_profile end
  picture.variant(combine_options: { resize: "100x100>", gravity: 'Center', extent: "100x100", background: 'white'}).processed.service_url
end
```

Code used in view

```
<%= image_tag current_admin.profile_picture, class: 'rounded-circle img-sidebar' %>
```

I already try to put

```
Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = "localhost"
```

When I change the active storage service to google, works great in localhost.

Comment: What version of Rails are you using?

Comment: You should be able to skip the `.processed.service_url` stuff and hand the variant directly to `image_tag`.

Comment: I'm using Rails 5.2.2 and @muistooshort why would this work? When I use google as storage it normally works.

Comment: It should work because `image_tag` knows how to build the URL and because [`processed`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveStorage/Variant.html#method-i-processed) is more about precomputing an image than anything else and [`service_url`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveStorage/Variant.html#method-i-service_url) is for building short-lived URLs. Drop back to the simplest solution and go from there.

Comment: Thanks @muistooshort :) I'll check if the performance is still good

Comment: You can call `processed` on the variant when the image is uploaded if you want to pre-build a particular variant.